# Postfix: Filter emails for my domain for helpdesk email

Tags: postfix, filter

My helpdesk system doesn't allow to filter by email. Some users send helpdesk tickets from their personal accounts by accident. I would like to make sure that only emails coming from domain.com will be forwarded. Every other mail account needs to be unaffected by this "filter".

My mailserver runs postfix on opensuse.
Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would use procmail.

Setup a .procmailrc for your helpdesk account.

```
# .procmailrc
# routes incoming mail to appropriate mailboxes
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
LOGFILE=/var/log/procmail.log
SHELL=/bin/sh

# Put mail from domain.com into default RT queue
:0:
* ^From: .+@domain\.com
| /usr/local/rt3/bin/rt-mailgate --queue default --action correspond --url http://localhost/
```

All you need to do is create a file called .forward in the helpdeskuser home dir that looks like this:

```
"|IFS=' ' && exec /usr/bin/procmail -f- || exit 75 #helpdeskuser"
```

http://www.procmail.org/